# My database code returning error : Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database

// connect_db.php

```
<?php
class Database_Connect{
    protected $dbHost;
    protected $dbUser;
    protected $dbPassword;
    protected $dbName;
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct($server, $user, $password, $database){
        $this->dbHost       = $server;
        $this->dbUser       = $user;
        $this->dbPassword   = $password;
        $this->dbName       = $database;
        $this->conn         = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
    }
    public function db_Check(){
        if($this->conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection Failed : ". $this->conn->connect_error);
        }
        else{
            echo "Successfully connected to Mysql database";
        }
    }

}
$invoke = new Database_Connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
$invoke->db_check(); 
?>
```

// create_table.php

```
<?php
include("connect_db.php");

class Create extends Database_Connect
{
    public function __construct(){

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE Myfriends (
                    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY 
                    KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
                    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
                    email VARCHAR(50), reg_date TIMESTAMP
                )";

        if ($this->conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
        } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $this->conn->error;
        }

        $this->conn->close();
    }

}
$create = new Create();
```

My database code returning a Fatal error :"Call to a member function query() on a non-object".
I failed to call the member function query in connect_db.php. USing parent::__construct() in create_table.php returning many errors. Please help me fix this bug.

Comment: protected $conn;  should be public ..? i guess...

Comment: explain where is conn is publicly defined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guyzzz. I have made it public but yet returning the same error.